# Page tabs iframe height working in only half the browsers

Tags: height, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe, facebook-page, facebook-canvas

I've done my homework and done what was ask to get the height of my page to set itself in my iFrame.

it works in Firefox (7+ at least), IE9
not working in Chrome, Safari, IE8/7 and Opera...
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Brunet/190517411026916?sk=app_136821946424212

the code is this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '136821946424212', // App ID
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.Canvas.setSize({width: 520, height: 1625});
  };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

all the docs and help out there point to this code working... am I missing somthing???

Comment: Is it not resizing at all, or resizing but still leaving scrollbars? And is 1625 the exact pixel height of your page?  I've found that you have to pad that by 20px or so to prevent scroll bars, so if that's the issue try 1650px.

Comment: in other browsers than Firefox 7/8 and Ie9, IT DOES NOT resize at all, it crop the page (no scrollbar, witch is normal, i've tell him overflow:hidden on the body)

Comment: I can't any reason the code shouldn't work, but for debugging I would try the following: 1) put an `alert` right after the `FB.Canvas.setSize` call to make sure it is actually being executed; 2) delete the entire `FB.init` call (not needed just for resizing); and 3) temporarily eliminate all CSS on the page (something with fixed height could be throwing things off, and having scrollbars can help see the height of the iframe itself which might actually be changing).

Comment: i've set an alert after the setSize and : 
the alert show in  FF7/8 and IE9, but not in Chrome, so, Chrome does not start window.fbAsyncInit ?

Comment: see: http://primemarketing.ca/_fbpt/brunet/

Comment: Well... there is a **problem**, it works... well it works on other "machines" but i've got no plugin in my IE/Safari/Opera and it's affecting my Chrome too... bizare!

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me in Chrome, so I'm not sure where the problem is.  It might be worth trying a different arrangement, using an onload event rather than fbAsyncInit:

```
<head>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload=function() {
  FB.Canvas.setSize({width:520,height:1650});
}
</script>
</head>
```